# Different mapping behavior for the different visual modes?

Tags: key-bindings

I want to have different behavior for the different visual modes. As an example if I wanted to `vnoremap S{` so that it has the following behavior:

- surrounds the selection in `v mode`, (puts `{` at the start of selection and and `}` at the end of selection)
- surrounds the lines in `V mode`, (puts `{` above and `}` below the selected lines)
- surrounds the block in `ctrl-v mode`, (puts`{`s on the left edge and and `}`s on the right edge)

what would that look like? I have this but its buggy (behavior isn't consistent, seems to toggle behavior on every attempt.

```
vnoremap <expr> S{ visualmode() ==# "v" ?
\ "<Esc>`>a}<Esc>`<i{<Esc>" : visualmode() ==# "V" ?
\ "<Esc>`>o}<Esc>`<O{<Esc>va{=" :
\ "A}<Esc>gvI{<Esc>"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `visualmode()` which returns the last used visual mode, not the current one.

```
                   vvvvvvvvvvvv
vnoremap <expr> S{ visualmode() ==# "v" ?
\ "<Esc>`>a}<Esc>`<i{<Esc>" : visualmode() ==# "V" ?
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You need the current one, which is given by `mode()`:

```
                   vvvvvv
vnoremap <expr> S{ mode() ==# "v" ?
\ "<Esc>`>a}<Esc>`<i{<Esc>" : mode() ==# "V" ?
                              ^^^^^^
```

---

Unrelated to the issue, but you don't need to call `[visual]mode()` several times, and `xnoremap` is better than `vnoremap`:

```
xno <expr> S{ {
\  'v': "\e`>a}\e`<i{\e",
\  'V': "\e`>o}\e`<O{\eva{=",
\  '<c-v>': "A}\egvI{\e",
\ }[mode()]
```

Comment: "which returns the last used visual mode"
That explains the toggling behavior of what I had. Thanks. Also, thanks for suggesting a cleaner way to map it